# Getting `initialize': wrong number of arguments(1 for 0) (ArgumentError) for simple ruby app

Tags: ruby, arguments

This is my first ruby app. And I am a stack overflow virgin... When I run the following program:

```
class NameApp

def intialize(name)
    @names = []
end

def name_question
    print "What is your name? "
    answer = gets.chomp
    @names += answer.to_s
    puts "The number of characters in your name is " + names.length
end


def name_length
    if @names.length > 25 then 
        print "Your name is longer than 25 characters."
    else 
        print "Your name is too short."
    end
end

end

name_app = NameApp.new("Test1")
name_app.class # => NameApp

name_app.name_question
name_app.name_length
```

I get this simple error message result:

```
name.rb:26:in `initialize': wrong number of arguments(1 for 0) (ArgumentError)
from nameapp.rb:26:in `new'
from nameapp.rb:26:in `<main>'
```

Can you help me trouble shoot?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since you have not defined the method `initialize` for `NameApp`, by default, it takes zero arguments, but you passed one argument `"Test1"` via the constructor `new`.

Comment: Answer below regarding `initialize` being misspelt is more useful.

Comment: @RyanSandridge Why? That answer is just based on a guess.

Comment: It isn't based on a guess. The code sample clearly shows that `initialize` was misspelled  as `intialize`. Your answer is correct, that the method `initialize` was not defined; however pointing out that it was simply a spelling mistake is more useful.

Answer (score 70):

You spelled "initialize" wrong.  I did that a few times too when I was starting out, and that was hard to debug.  Why ruby didn't name it "init", I'll never know.

Answer (score 0):

For `require_relative 'user'` move old 'user.rb' up one level rename 'user2.rb' to 'user.rb'. Also, there is a typo.

Answer (score 0):

If you're reading this thread and you spelled `initialize` correctly the issue might be related to your `super` call.

This fails:

```rb
def initialize(bar:)
  super
  @bar = bar
end
```

And this works:

```rb
def initialize(bar:)
  super()
  @bar = bar
end
```